# web api calls routing to wrong method

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a webapi controller which goes against the default webapi convention to expose a few different "get" methods

```
    [HttpGet]
    [WebAPIValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute]
    public Manufacturer[] GetManufacturers()
    {
        var profiler = MiniProfiler.Current; 
        using (profiler.Step("WCF Service Call: GetManufacturers"))
        {
            return IvService.GetManufacturers();
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [WebAPIValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute]
    public Range[] GetRanges(string manufacturer_code)
    {
        var profiler = MiniProfiler.Current;
        using (profiler.Step("WCF Service Call: GetRanges"))
        {
            return IvService.GetRanges(manufacturerCode);
        }
    }
```

They are very simple methods which are called from Javascript and make another call out to an external system via WCF, then return the result.  This has been working fine on dev for a while but recently stopped working- both calls from javascript to GetManufacturers and GetRanges now hit the same break point in GetManufacturers.  I checked fiddler and its definitely calling the correct url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some refactoring had taken place to enforce some coding standards to do with parameter names and the call from javascript had been adjusted to from

```
VehicleController/GetRanges?manufacturer_code=AB
```

to

```
VehicleController/GetRanges?manufacturerCode=AB
```

without adjusting the corresponding webapi method.  At first I had suspected this was some weird routing issue but it turns out because the parameters names no longer contained anything it recognized, it resolved to the only method which didn't required any parameters, which makes sense but kept me scratching my head for a little while!